# php not executing another script

Tags: php

I have a .php file that looks like this:

```
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $array)
              {
            echo '<div class="thumb" style="width: '.$array['thumb_width'].'px; height: '.$array['thumb_height'].'px;">
            <p><a href="showfile.php?image_id='.$array['image_id'].'">
            <img src="showthumbs.php?image_id='.$array['image_id'].'" alt="'.$array['image_name'].' /">
            </a></p>
            <p>'.$array['image_name'].'</p></div>';
            }
```

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html#7) to basically upload and show images. When I view source the page that is loaded ([which you can test out here](http://renps.nm3.co/galerry.php)), for some reason it's not displaying the image. I have the showthumbs.php on the same location as the location of the gallery.php. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probalby have a line break before your `<?php` tag.  That means something has already been output to the response body when you try to set the header.  And Headers must be set before the Body is sent. Otherwise you get the error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Just look for any chars before `<?php` in showthumbs.php.  My guess is it's a space or new line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your showthumbs.php. You need to tell the browser that the page returns an image. Right now, it is trying to take the image data and parse it as if it were text.

To do so, add the following line to showthumbs.php (before you output the image):

```
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
```

Comment: if you see the link I posted to the tutorial it shows that showthumbs.php does call that header call...

Comment: @adit the tutorial you posted uses the line:  header("Content-type: ".$array['image_type']);

Comment: As an FYI, it is bad practice to store the image blob in your database. Store the image as a native file and have your database point to the filename.

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure this is related...

on your page: (the one you're trying to use as the image)
http://renps.nm3.co/showthumbs.php?image_id=1

you got an echo or something that says OH MY GOD and create an error...

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/renps/public_html/showthumbs.php:2) in /home/renps/public_html/showthumbs.php on line 41
```

Comment: so what does this mean that headers has been sent... how do I fix this

Comment: in your php, check for a print_r you forgot or something like that *do ctrl+f and search GOD

Comment: yes I removed that.. it's a var dump, now I am just confused with the header warning

Comment: warning was just because you already dumped something before calling it... now it's just a prob with your SQL structure (probably a typo on your create or you forgot it.) your new error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image_size' in 'field list'

Comment: that other error is when you click on the link, which is the showfile.php.. I am not concerned about that.. more concerned with the showthumbs.php not loaded in this gallery.php. I should see an image there right?

Comment: not if the parent php generate an error. if your php calls an SQL error he stops and doesn't reach your header request.